# Dialogflow/ API.AI for Google Home Mini App

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

This is my very first question and seems to be easy but coding it is somehow difficult...

So, basically I've got an Agent that should just call a URL and get the content of the website. This should then be spoken out by the smart speaker.
I already have a webhook working but now I'm stuck at getting the web-content..

Would be awesome if someone could please help me out here.
Best regards

Comment: It might be helpful to try out a codelab like https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-action-on-google-with-webhook/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex

Comment: If you can post the code that you have working, what you've tried, and where exactly you're "stuck", we might be able to point you in a better direction.

Comment: We definitely need more info. Are using the node sdk on the fulfillment side? https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Getting the web content is not easy . you have to parse the content in a web page using program , a simple logic is to detect '<' and '>' and remove all strings in between using string functions

Best of luck with that